# Page refreshing after replacing the current route in vue js 3( Component getting unmounted and mounted again)

Tags: javascript, routes, vuejs3, mount, unmount

I have been using `router.replace` method to add the params in my existing url. But the page is getting refreshed and my settings ( setting a value in the dropdown) getting reset. Any solution for this?

I have tried `router.replace` method and `history.replace` method.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is nothing in your problem description that suggests why your page is reloading.  `router.replace` on its own does not cause a full page reload.  The issue is likely something else related to how you call router.replace (form submit?) or how you load the component or route, but we would need more information/code to confirm.

Comment: I have a dropdown in my page (component) . If I select a value from the dropdown, it should be added as a param in the URL as well as push a new value into the dropdown. When i debug the code, first it will push the value, then due to route change, the page will refresh and reset to the old values in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Use this router.push()

// literal string path
router.push('/users/eduardo')

// object with path
router.push({ path: '/users/eduardo' })

// named route with params to let the router build the url
router.push({ name: 'user', params: { username: 'eduardo' } })

// with query, resulting in /register?plan=private
router.push({ path: '/register', query: { plan: 'private' } })

// with hash, resulting in /about#team
router.push({ path: '/about', hash: '#team' })

[enter link description here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).